# how to remove time on timeline calendar using full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have made a timeline 7 days calendar using full-calendar. But instead of time, I need only dates. I don't need time. I only want dates like 12/18 12/19 12/20 etc. 
Here is my code:

```
$(function() { // document ready

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  now: '2017-12-07',
  editable: false, // enable draggable events
  aspectRatio: 1.9,
  scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'timelineThreeDays'
  },
  defaultView: 'timelineThreeDays',
  views: {
    timelineThreeDays: {
      type: 'timeline',
      duration: { days: 7 }
    }
  },
  resourceLabelText: 'Inventory',
  resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
    { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
    { id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [
      //{ id: 'd1', title: 'Room D1' },
      //{ id: 'd2', title: 'Room D2' }
    ] },
    { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E' },
    { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
    { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
    { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H' },
    { id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I' },
    { id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J' },
    { id: 'k', title: 'Auditorium K' },
    { id: 'l', title: 'Auditorium L' },
    { id: 'm', title: 'Auditorium M' },
    { id: 'n', title: 'Auditorium N' },
    { id: 'o', title: 'Auditorium O' },
    { id: 'p', title: 'Auditorium P' },
    { id: 'q', title: 'Auditorium Q' },
    { id: 'r', title: 'Auditorium R' },
    { id: 's', title: 'Auditorium S' },
    { id: 't', title: 'Auditorium T' },
    { id: 'u', title: 'Auditorium U' },
    { id: 'v', title: 'Auditorium V' },
    { id: 'w', title: 'Auditorium W' },
    { id: 'x', title: 'Auditorium X' },
    { id: 'y', title: 'Auditorium Y' },
    { id: 'z', title: 'Auditorium Z' }
  ],
  events: [
    //{ id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-12-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-12-07T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
    //{ id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2017-12-07T05:00:00', end: '2017-12-07T22:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
    { id: '3', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-12-07', end: '2017-12-12', title: 'Hold' },
    { id: '4', resourceId: 'd', start: '2017-12-07', end: '2017-12-10', title: 'Available' },
    //{ id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2017-12-07T03:00:00', end: '2017-12-07T08:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
    //{ id: '5', resourceId: 'f', start: '2017-12-07T00:30:00', end: '2017-12-07T02:30:00', title: 'event 5' }
  ]
});
```

});

If I remove scrollTime no luck. Can anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you want the intervals displayed on the timeline to be in whole days, rather than shorter intervals of a few hours or minutes.

To do this, as per the documentation, you have to set the "slotDuration" option:

```
slotDuration: '24:00'
```

gets you a 24-hr (1-day) interval displayed.

See http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/3/ for a demo.

Comment: yes perfect. I need this "slotDuration". Thank you @ADyson

Comment: @ADyan, How to do the same thing in V5 ? I tried this it didn't works. Thank you